# What does 0x0 indicate in the instruction

Tags: gdb

What does `0x0` indicate in the following instruction -
`lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That entire statement is a great noop it looks to be a 7-byte noop.

http://www.technovelty.org/code/arch/noop.html

Comment: Your welcome. In short it's a very convoluted way to load the value in esi into esi in 7 bytes.  (If you like the answer bump my score ;) )

Comment: Definatly i will do once is get once i get 15 reputation :(.. Looks it will take few days

Comment: I think you can check the answer to indicate that it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

It indicates an offset value of zero.

Comment: Thanks, Also what is the effective destination address ? I dont understand   (%esi,%eiz,1)