# What does INSTR 0x0(REG), REG, 0x0 displacement mean?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

I was looking in to some compiler generated assembly code(x86_64) and found few instructions which have a zero displacement as following..

```
     movzbl 0x0(%rbp),%eax
```

What could be the reason behind such 0x0 displacement? (I am new to assembly, please point me to the links if its already a discussed issue.) From my understanding, the above instruction *copies the zero extended rbp+(0x0) to eax*.

---

EDIT: I found a link which explains it for **leal** though
[what-does-0x0-indicate-in-the-instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985635/what-does-0x0-indicate-in-the-instruction)

Thank you..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means `movzx eax, byte [rbp + 0]`.

There's no encoding for memory operands at address contained in `(e|r)bp`, but there is for `(e|r)bp + constant`. So, you have 0 for that constant to extract a byte from the address in `rbp`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but I couldn't get what you mean by encoding! Are you talking about the registers being addressable as rax(eax(ah, al))) ? (Whereas that is not possible with rbp/rsp)

Comment: Every instruction is encoded as a sequence of bytes. Some bits of those bytes determine the instruction's "opcode" (`movzx`), others determine the operands (`eax` and `byte [rbp + 0]`, respectively). There is no bit combination to represent the operand `[rbp]`. But there is one for `[rbp + some integer constant]`. It's just how the designers chose to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and clear explanation!! It makes sense to me now :)